# MySQL - Maximum execution time

Tags: xampp

I turned on xampp and when I want mysql it writes me this:
*Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\ErrorHandler.php on line 191*

Don't know what to do with it?
I had to set this in php.ini: max_execution_time=0, but localhost/phpmyadmin/ still doesn't work.